# Reciprocal of complex function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact metric space, let $f \in C(K;\mathbb{C})$ be a continuous function. Let $e$ be the constant $1$ function.

> Prove that $\lambda e-f$ has a reciprocal if and only if $\lambda \notin f(K)$

- If $\lambda =f(k) \in f(K)$, then, assuming $g$ is the reciprocal of $\lambda e -f$, we get $1=e(k)=g(k)(\lambda e(k)-f(k))=0$
- If $\lambda \notin f(K)$, then $(\lambda e -f)(K)\subseteq \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and since the reciprocal of an element is a continuous function is a continuous function $ \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow  \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, by composition also $1/(\lambda e -f)$ is continuous.

Is everything correct? I'm asking because I didn't really use compactness here.

For some context I'm learnign about spectral theory of Banach Algebras.

Thank you!

Comment: the result is true for any set, however $C(K;\mathbb{C})$ is not a Banach algebra in general if $K$ not compact

Comment: We are "using" compactness in that $C(K;\mathbb{C})=C_b(K;\mathbb{C})$ for compact $K$ and $C_b$ has the sup norm for Banach algebra structure.